# repeater advanced custom field and post meta key

Tags: repeater, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to display various custom post types such as Paper, Publication, Events, Media linked to a person on their profile page.

E.g when we add a Paper/Publications we link single/multiple peoples associated with this paper. The 'people' is a repeater field "linked_author" with "paper_linked_author" as sub-field (post object).

So, people profile will have the following:
- Policy 
- Publication 
- Media 
- Events

How can I do that?

Comment: Forgot to mention that 'people' is also a custom post type.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be thinking about it backwards, if you want to display these linked Post Types on a people page then maybe it's easier to have your custom fields on the People page instead.

Comment: I was able to display the list of custom post publication type linked to the author on its profile page by below code however only when I write the author's id value '3633' manually. 
<code>
$args = array(
 'numberposts' => -1,
 'post_type'  => 'publications',
 'meta_query' => array(
  'relation'  => 'AND',
  array(
   'key'  => 'linked_author_$_paper_linked_author',
   'compare' => '=',
   'value'  => '3633'
   
  )
 )
);
</code>
If I want to dynamically change the value based on author ID, I'm not able to to do that.

Comment: Am I right in thinking that you're working on the single-people.php template? Can't you just pass 'value' => get_the_ID() or am I misunderstanding what you're trying to do?

Comment: Mar, yes using get_the_ID worked. I have created a plugin people and in single-people.php I'm trying to link all of the custom post to this author on his profile page. Your suggestion helped me a lot. Thanks.